# domPdf is showing blank page

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

Nothing is showing on the page.

library/pdf.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
// Dompdf namespace use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdf{
    public function __construct(){
        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
        $pdf = new DOMPDF(); $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->dompdf = $pdf; 
    } 
    
}
?>
```

Controller

```
function invoice(){
        $data_user = array();
        $data_user['users'] = $this->db->get('users')->limit(2)->result();
        $this->load->view('invoice',$data_user);
        $html = $this->output->get_output();
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $this->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $this->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
        $this->dompdf->render();
        $this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
   }
```

I tried to change html to find if html is causing issue. To test, I did keep only one h3 heading. But still got blank page.

Comment: Please add more code/details/error messages. What happens when you var-_dump($html) or var_dump($this->dompdf)?

Comment: @b126 Nothing comes, no error, no warning. Complete white screen. Even with var_dump of $html and $this->dompdf also shows nothing.

Comment: Can you put your .env into DEVELOPMENT? Is your route well defined? It used to work before?